# Razor pages: how to debug wrong page handler used when posting form?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a form containing this code:

`<form asp-page="TodoItem" asp-page-handler="Delete" method="post" id="myItem">`

When I submit this form in my browser, a POST fires to `https://localhost:44311/TodoItem?handler=Delete` according to the network tab in my browser's F12 DevTools. So far so good.

But what happens in my Razor Pages project, is that on my `TodoItem`page, the `OnPost` is being run, instead of the `Delete` method which I wanted to run.

How can I debug this? I have the loglevel for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` already at `Trace`, it's only showing the URL in the logs, not the query string in the URL.

Also it seems I can replace the handler name with anything, so `TodoItem?handler=Foobarzy` also runs the `OnPost`, which fails completely silently - Visual Studio doesn't tell me that I'm specifying a non-existent handler using IntelliSense, the logs (in the console) don't tell me that a browser has made a strange request. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods, your method should be named as `OnPost<Action>Async`. The value passed to the page-handler attribute is the name of the handler method without the OnPost prefix or Async suffix. Is it true? Could you provide handlers code ?

Comment: Thanks, I named it OnPostDelete (didn't add async to the name) and it works! Still find it hard to debug, I switched to C# to avoid silent errors like this.

Comment: No problem, async suffix usually used for indicating whether method is asynchronous or not